# How do I sum() values from nodes created in a XSLT variable

Tags: xslt, xpath, sum, node-set

I'm having trouble with sum'ing up values in a variable.

XSLT Source

```
 <xsl:variable name="amountIn" xml:space="preserve">
 <values>
 <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($finData)//child::balance/@in">
 <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </values>
 </xsl:variable>
```

XML source:

```
 <source>
 <balance dpt="-1" diff="0,00" out="555777,00" in="555777,00" acnt="2120"/> 
 <balance dpt="-1" diff="0,00" out="777778,00" in="777778,00" acnt="2240"/> 
 <balance dpt="-1" diff="0,00" out="878787,00" in="878787,00" acnt="2380"/> 
 <balance dpt="-1" diff="0,00" out="87878787,00" in="87878787,00" acnt="2400"/>
 </source>
```

I expected this to give me the result, but all I get is "NaN"

```
 <xsl:value-of select="sum(ext:node-set($amountIn)/values/value)"/>
```

Comment: XSLT version 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: That's because numbers don't have commas in them. (European formatting is not recognized by XSLT).

Comment: Please clarify: Is in="555777,00" meant to be value 555777.00 ?

Comment: Correct, the source uses ',' instead of '.' for decimals. TreeMonkey answered correct below - using translate fixed the problem.
Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are getting NAN because of the , in the number using the translate number to change this into a . should work!

```
 <xsl:variable name="amountIn" xml:space="preserve">
 <values>
 <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($finData)//child::balance/@in">
 <value><xsl:value-of select="translate(.,',','.')"/></value>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </values>
 </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: +1. Beat me to it. I set up a working demo of this principle (well, similar) [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/IJ2SD1).